# How to fix character spacing in Word object linked to Excel data

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm linking data from excel into a word object, but when the data appears in word the character spacing is changed and all the letters blend together:

**Data as it appears in Excel:** (*Font = Calibri*)

[image]

**Object appearance in Word:**

[image]

You can't adjust character spacing in Excel, and I've already tried a number of different fonts, but it still looks awful. What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the link in your Word document and select Format Object from the pop-up menu.  This will open the Format Object dialog.

Then select the Size tab.

Towards the bottom left, UNTICK Lock aspect ratio.

Then in the Scale boxes just above, change both Height and Width to 100.

Click OK and you should now see a normally formatted image in your Word doc.

Comment: Does nothing, the problem is not with the aspect of the image, it's with the way the image is generated. Adjusting the aspect ratio does not affect character spacing.